# Chat over LAN with Win7 PC?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have two PCs (one Win7 and one Ubuntu 13.04) connected to the internet via the same router, on the same wi-fi network.

Is there any software I can install on both PCs so that the two users can text chat with each other over the LAN, without access to anyone else on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Install **openssh-server** on Ubuntu and download [Putty](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe) on Windows machine.

open terminal on Ubuntu and launch Putty and login into Ubuntu from Windows.

Run **wall** command on both ends and start chatting. Type something and hit ctrl-d to "send" it. Ctrl-c finishes chat.

You can play with **talk** or **write** commands as well.

Comment: Thanks @jet....I'll give it a try, but I was looking for a more GUI based approach....

Comment: Something that would appeal to the non-linux person using windows!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use skype? Search for it in the software center, and if it asks to add a software source just let it.

Comment: @handuel...Thanks... but I am looking for a simple text chat interface..I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Apache Web Server on Ubuntu with php support enabled, you can use browsers.

Install this little script (which is a chat servlet):
https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/script-chat-simple_s2